# Single-Page Play Application

Tags: javascript, rest, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've just read about single-page web applications that expose a RESTful interface for retrieving the data - for example in JSON format, and that just provide a single HTML page referencing the Javascript file responsible for invoking the RESTful interface and building the web user interface dynamically in the client's web browser.

To implement this in Play, one should implement the controllers so that they return JSON instead of HTLM and implement some CoffeScript for rendering the user interface on the client side.

So far so good... but I'm wondering whether this design makes sense for large web applications since the amount of javascript code to be run on the client side would increase more and more.

My initial idea was to implement the web application using Play's template engine and then to provide a RESTful interface for Mobile apps.

Any suggestion, idea, or link to documentation that covers this topic would be really appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing a common REST API should work fine. At the moment I am working with a Play 2.0 server app for browser (Backbone etc) and iOS clients. The browser client is totally separate from the Play app and deployed independently.

I think there is some initial overhead compared to Play template approach but having just one set of controllers to test etc makes life easier.

Couple points to consider:

- Client authentication. Preferably you would use the same way for all the clients.
- At some point you might want to introduce some specialized REST API for one of the clients in order to save bandwith and number of requests. For example mobile landing screen is a typical candidate.
- You need to document your REST APIs more detailed as the web client devs are not sharing the codebase.

Answer (score 2):

The [Play for Scala book](http://www.manning.com/hilton/) has a chapter on this topic. They use a single view as an entry point, that's it.

As for large applications, that's a valid concern. For that you might want to use libraries such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) (which Play 2.1 has built-in support for), among others. You also might want to split your app into sub-modules to manage complexity. On the client side, you probably should use a framework, too, such as [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/).

Concerning Play there's not much left to say, it's a very good platform to expose RESTful JSON services. I recommend you take a look at the [JSON documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaJson) and also check out [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/).